# Composer Autoloading classes not found

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

I have folder structure like:

```
includes/
  libraries/
    Classes/
      Contact/
        Contact.php
        ContactController.php

admin/
  controllers/
    contact/
      edit.php
```

Contact.php is my class that file that I'm trying to use. The file contains.

```
<?php
namespace Classes;

class Contact {
    function __construct() {
        die('here');
    }
}
```

I have my composer.json file like:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Classes\\": "includes/libraries/Classes/"
        }
    },
}
```

The file I'm trying to use the Contact class in is `edit.php` within the `admin/controllers/contact/` folder. My `edit.php` file is like:

```
<?php

use Classes\Contact;

$contact = new Contact();

var_dump($contact);
```

This file has the `vendor/autoload.php` file included, yet I can't seem to get it to use the class?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Classes/Contact/Contact.php` and the composer rule `"Classes\\": "includes/libraries/Classes/"` imply `Classes\Contact\Contact` class, not `Classes\Contact`.

So if you actually want `Classes\Contact` class, move the `Classes/Contact/Contact.php` file up to the parent directory: `Classes/Contact.php`.

If, however, the desired namespace path to the class is `Classes\Contact\Contact`, then change the `use`:

```
use Classes\Contact\Contact;
```

And the `namespace`:

```
namespace Classes\Contact;

class Contact {}
```

### Example

```
├── composer.json
├── includes
│   └── libraries
│       └── Classes
│           └── Contact
│               └── Contact.php
├── test.php
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    └── composer
        ├── autoload_classmap.php
        ├── autoload_namespaces.php
        ├── autoload_psr4.php
        ├── autoload_real.php
        ├── autoload_static.php
        ├── ClassLoader.php
        ├── installed.json
        └── LICENSE
```

The files under `vendor/` are generated by composer.

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "testpsr4",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Classes\\": "includes/libraries/Classes"
        }
    }
}
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Classes\Contact\Contact;

$c = new Contact;
$c->test();
```

**includes/libraries/Classes/Contact/Contact.php**

```
<?php
namespace Classes\Contact;

class Contact {
    public function test () {
        echo __METHOD__, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Testing**

```
composer update
php test.php
```

**Output**

```
Classes\Contact\Contact::test
```

Comment: Okay, should I have the rule `use Classes/Contact/Contact;` then?

Comment: @RyanHipkiss, no, just move the PHP file to parent directory. Ah, if you want `Classes/Contact/Contact`, then yes, don't move the file, and change the `use`.

Comment: Or use namespace `Classes\Contact` instead of `Classes`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try this.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov I've changed it to use the new use and namespaces, and rerun `composer dump-autoload`, but no result. Class still not found.

Comment: @RyanHipkiss, I've added example of full configuration and the commands to test it.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov I don't know whats changed, but its worked. Thank you :)