# How to autoload with composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to get the composer autoloader to work for an hour now and I'm out of ideas. Looked at about 2 dozen stack overflow answers but still don't understand how it works:

I am trying to create a `new ClientRepository()` from [this composer package](http://oauth2.thephpleague.com/installation/).

[See example of usage](http://oauth2.thephpleague.com/authorization-server/auth-code-grant/)

**My php file**

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$clientRepository = new ClientRepository();
```

I already tried the following:

- `new League\OAuth2\Server\Repositories\ClientRepository();`
- `new League\OAuth2\Server\ClientRepository();`
- `new League\ClientRepository();`
- `new League\Repositories\ClientRepository();`

**Structure of composer folders**

[image]

Comment: echo you `__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php'` is correct path

Comment: Yes this is correct :)

Comment: Which framework you are using?

Comment: None, I just use composer to download the lib and I'm trying to use it in a very simple script but I simply can't access the classes....

Comment: I think here you can find the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer Autoloading classes not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126706/composer-autoloading-classes-not-found)

Comment: I don't see how the reffered question helps me :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class *ClientRepository* is not part of package *league/oauth2-server* although it's used in some sample code in package documentation. You will need to create it first (by implementing interface *\League\OAuth2\Server\Repositories\ClientRepositoryInterface*) then use it, which is too complicate for the question.

If you only want to see how Composer works for that package, following piece of code should work:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$request = new League\OAuth2\Server\RequestTypes\AuthorizationRequest();
?>
```

or

```
<?php
use League\OAuth2\Server\RequestTypes\AuthorizationRequest;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$request = new AuthorizationRequest();
?>
```