# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ClientRepository' not found

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, autoload

I use this code:

```
require_once __DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php";

use League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\PasswordGrant;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Repositories\ClientRepositoryInterface;

$clientRepository = new ClientRepository();
```

But I get error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ClientRepository' not found in
>   /home/a/public_html/app/oauth2.php:23 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /home/a/public_html/app/oauth2.php on line 23

Comment: You should probably ```use``` ```ClientRepository``` as well, or instead of ```ClientRepositoryInterface```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to autoload with composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49336656/how-to-autoload-with-composer)

Comment: I added use `League\OAuth2\Server\Repositories\ClientRepository;` but not work

Comment: @Ogreucha I read that reply, but not work for me

Comment: @user12330913 you have to create your own ClientRepository class as mentioned in that answer.

Comment: @Ogreucha How I can?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you forgot namespace:

```
require_once __DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php";

use League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\PasswordGrant;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Repositories\ClientRepositoryInterface;

use NamespaceClass\ClientRepository; <-- edit

$clientRepository = new ClientRepository();
```

Comment: I added use `League\OAuth2\Server\Repositories\ClientRepository;` but not work

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'League\OAuth2\Server\Repositories\ClientRepository' not found in

Comment: @user12330913 I think you need create ClientRepository class and he must implement ClientRepositoryInterface https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/client-repository-interface/

Comment: How I can create this class? and where?

Answer (score 0):

You must create ClientRepository class in project.

```
class ClientRepository implements ClientRepositoryInterface {
    // Code here
}
```

You can read more here:

https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/database-setup/

https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/issues/1067